# Creating a php script to run as cron job - using the Zend Framework library

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

I am creating a php script that would be called as a cron job. However I need to use the functionalities of the Zend framework. The thing is that relative referencing of files especially in includes don't work when programming for being run via command line so I'm stuck with how do I use the zend libraries here. I don't want to go in and change every single require_once statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP is probably using a different php.ini file when called through the CLI (Command Line Interface).

Use [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) to detect whether you're running in CLI mode, and [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-include-path.php) to force the correct include path.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to set the include path of the Zend lib.